# Is there something like Django debug page or DjDT in Java?

Tags: java, python, debugging, web

When I get an error while working with JSP/servlets it is shown a page  like this:

[image]

Despite being sufficient to track the majority of the problems, I was wondering if there is some components that you can add to your web application to give you more debugging info (for example: something like Django debug page/ debug toolbar that shows session data, SQL queries executed, etc).

[image]

I know Java and Python are two very different worlds, and even those two tools are specific to Django. But there are some tools in Java similar in purpose the ones I referred early?

Comment: Not directly and answer to your question on `JSP` hence posting as comment.  In in the `Java` World where now a lot of people use `JSF` for the presentation layer, `facelets` has a `<ui:debug />` tag which does something similar to what you have shown.

Comment: @rgeorge Can you write an answer based in your comment? Probably that is the closest available tool.

Comment: I asked a similar (now deleted) question as there is also a very sophisticated toolbar for Symfony (PHP) but I know nothing comparable in the Java world. Rails seems to even have multiple, e.g. Rack insight.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.xml you can map the error code to specific pages in the form:

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>500</error-code>
 <location>/errors/servererror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and print the debug info directly in the jsp page.

Comment: Thanks jsfviky71 but I'm looking to an improve in the debugging of pages: some tool that can add more info to that page. Probably there is nothing similar in Java...